# Django how to phasing the dollar sign using os.environ.get( )

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux

I'm coding Django program,code is running in Linux, the env file includes :

```
 "PWD=uTfa$aB67"
```

in settings.py:

```
PWD = os.environ.get('PWD')
```

Then in the code where I need this password ,I code:

```
password = settings.PWD
```

However every time when I print 'password' ,I only got:

```
uTfa
```

I have tried single quotes ,but it not works. Any suggestion ?

Comment: try: PWD="uTfa\$aB67"

Comment: I tried  "PWD=uTfa\$aB67",it does not work

Comment: No. Use PWD="uTfa\$aB67". You moved the double quotes

Comment: Ok ,let me try now.

Comment: still not working.